# Initialising 2D array/list in Python for 2 different varaibles

Tags: java, python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to port something from Java to Python and was curious how I would go about converting this method. It is used to initialise a 2D array with 2 different varaibles. Here is the code in Java:

```java
private void initialiseQvalues() {
    qTable = new float[numStates][numActions];
    // set q values initially to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numActions; j++) {
            qTable[i][j] = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

I have brought this over to Python with this function:

```py
def initialiseQvalues(self, numStates, numActions):
    self.qTable = [numStates][numActions]

    for i in range(0, numStates):
        for j in range(0, numActions):
            self.qTable[i][j] = 0.0
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\ninja\OneDrive\Desktop\Stuff\FYP\Gridworld\Agent.py", line 27, in initialiseQvalues
    self.qTable = [numStates][numActions]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have read about list compresion and other methods for 2D arrays, but as for 2D arrays with 2 different variables (NumStates, numActions), I have not seen anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses lists for normal processing, which are close to Java ArrayList objects. So you just initialize a list containing `numStates` (sub-)lists each containing `numActions` actions. If you go with explicits loops, appending to a list is much easier than  directly build lists of lists. So you could use:

```
def initialiseQvalues(self, numStates, numActions):
    self.qTable = []

    for i in range(0, numStates):
        self.qTable.append([])
        for j in range(0, numActions):
            self.qTable[i].append(0.0)
```

But the truely Pythonic way would be to use *comprehensions*:

```
def initialiseQvalues(self, numStates, numActions):
    return [[0.0 for j in range(numActions)] for i in range(numStates]
```

---

Python has a *beginners trap* with lists of lists (or more generaly with containers of mutable objects): the naive `[[0.0] * numStates] * numActions]` generates an outer list containing references to the very same object. Demo:

```
>>> tab = [[0.0] * 3] * 2
>>> tab
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
>>> tab[0][0] = 1.0
>>> tab
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Changing an element in a sub-list has changed the same element in all other sub-lists, because the outer list only contains a bunch of references to the same inner object.

Comment: Thanks very much! One small question as well, in terms of accessing and updating a specific value later on, would 
`self.qTable[previousState][selectedAction] = newQ` 
work?

Comment: @ConnnK: You have an example of it in my *demo code*... If `tab` is a list of lists, `tab[i][j]` is the j-th element of the i-th sub-list (indices starting at 0)

Answer (score 4):

In order to initialize a list of `n` duplicate values, you can use a list comprehension, like this:

```py
    def initialiseQvalues(self, numStates, numActions):
        self.qTable = [[0.0 for i in range(numActions)] for j in range(numStates)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonce. I was wondering, wouldnt that still make it a single array instead of a 2d? When updating a specific value such as
`self.qTable[previousState][selectedAction] = newQ`
 would that work still?

Comment: Beware! the outer lists will contain references to the same object! If you later write `self.qTable[0][0] = 1.0`, all `self.qTable[i][0` will be changed too...

Comment: @ConnnK Yeah, you are right. Just use the list comprehension version. Updated the answer